# MSAL Access Token identical to Id Token

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I have started using MSAL to authenticate my users from an Angular app to Azure AD.

I have configured Azure AD to return both ID and Access tokens. My understanding is that ID token contains info about user who signed in and can be passed through to the different component of the front end application in order to verify the user is authenticated.
The Access token can be used to authenticate calls to backend API.

In this case how come the token I receive I strictly identical ?

Comment: Can you post your code calling MSAL? I know that the previous version of the library would return both ID and access token in the same call, but the latest version requires both the login and acquireToken calls to get the ID and access tokens, respectively.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as this. After logging in, I'm making the the following call - which seems to be reading from cache. "msal.acquireTokenSilent({scopes: ['User.Read']}).then(r => console.log(r.accessToken))" The first time I made the call, it worked as expected and I was able to validate it against jtw.io. After that, I can't get seem to get the correct accessToken. I'm using msal 1.3.1 - not sure if it helps the OP